# How to clean duplicates existing in one folder from another recursively?

Tags: duplicate-files

**Summary:**

- Folder A has only many Excelent files
- Folder B has many folders of mixed Excelent/Good/Bad files

How can I delete files in Folder B folders only in case they will be in Folder A.

In other words, how to check if Folder A files exist in Folder B folders then delete from Folder B folders?

**Idea of solution**
Maybe a command which:

1. Checks part of alphabet like all starting with A
2. Executing deletion on files found in Folder B subfolders
3. Repeat 1. + one alphabet up.

Reasons why other duplication programs were bad:

1. Long time until 1st deletion - it's only when finished scanning
2. And no possibility to choose deleting in Folder B. It's possible only to keep latest and something else also, but not by choosing in which folder to keep.

**Useless history:** Files were copied from Recuva in Folder B and partly arranged, but a lot of them are bad. So first, I'm thinking Folder B comparing if exist to those which recovered again, but now just Excelent recovered in Folder A by Recuva so most of Excelent will be just in Folder A.

**Example file tree:**

```
.
├── A
│   ├── 1.png
│   ├── 2.png
│   └── Excellent
│       ├── e1.png
│       └── e2.png
└── B
    ├── 1.png
    ├── 2.png
    ├── Bad
    │   ├── 1.png
    │   ├── 2.png
    │   ├── e1.png
    │   └── e2.png
    └── Excellent
        ├── e1.png
        └── e2.png
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below are two solutions, depending on how we define "duplicate":

- Files with the same relative path, or
- Files with the same content but not necessarily the same name

---

If by "duplicate" we mean **two files which share the same relative path**, then you could use `find` and `xargs` to remove the duplicates. For example, suppose you have

```
~/tmp% tree A
A
└── Excellent
    ├── bar
    ├── baz
    └── foo
~/tmp% tree B
B
├── Bad
│   └── quux
├── Excellent
│   ├── bar
│   ├── baz
│   └── foo
└── Good
```

Then

```
find /home/unutbu/tmp/A  -depth -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} bash -c 'rm "/home/unutbu/tmp/B${1#*A}"' - {}
```

results in

```
~/tmp% tree B
B
├── Bad
│   └── quux
├── Excellent
└── Good
```

---

Or, if by "duplicate" we mean **two files share the same content**, though perhaps not the same filename, then you could use `rdfind`:

```
sudo apt-get install rdfind
```

If we have this directory structure:

```
~/tmp% tree A
A
└── Excellent
    ├── bar
    ├── baz
    └── foo

1 directory, 3 files
~/tmp% tree B
B
├── Bad
│   └── quux
├── Excellent
│   ├── barbar
│   ├── bazbaz
│   └── foofoo
└── Good
```

where `barbar` has the same content as `bar`, and similarly for `bazbaz` and `foofoo`, then

```
rdfind -deleteduplicates true A B
```

results in

```
~/tmp% tree B
B
├── Bad
│   └── quux
├── Excellent
└── Good
```

---

**Alternate solution** in case your version of Ubuntu does not include rdfind:

You could instead use `fdupes`:

```
sudo apt-get install fdupes
fdupes --recurse --delete --noprompt A B
```

Comment: Maybe its couse im on Ubuntu 10.04 but 1st solution isnt working. For testing i made folder Good and B. In Good is 1 file. In B is 2 subfolders both have 2 files. Command i did kangarooo@kangarooo-laptop:~/000 Test Dups$ find Good/ -depth -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} bash -c 'rm "B${1#*A}"' - {}
rm: cannot remove `BGood/vlcsnap-2012-12-11-01h36m32s101.png': No such file or directory

And other programm isnt in 10.04 ill try when ill get to some 12.04 but is there alternative to 10.04 also?

Comment: In your command, change `B${1#*A}` to `B${1#*Good}`. This is a bash expression which removes `Good` from the filename and replaces it with `B`. The tools used in this solution fairly common to all versions of unix, and should work fine in Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Ah yes i see now what was A in there. Ok it works but not if i post to Folder B. It worked if i put it to check subfolder. Is there some recursive option also?
And http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/rdfind isnt in 10.04 (lucid) but ill try to get on some 12.04. Ill use combination of both. 1st to delete exact names. Then more cleaning and then exact sizes. Exact sizes is better but since couse of not having exact sizes couse of Excelent/Bad/Good variations of same file then they will have different sizes. But ill do some backup and check test exact comparison command also.

Comment: WOW i just understood this is SUPER AMAZING command! It will check files one by one deleting if it exists in B folder. But missing is checking in recusive subfolders of B.

Comment: Searching [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com) for packages that contain the word "duplicate" in its description yielded [fdupes](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/fdupes). This should work in place of `rdfind`.

Comment: How to make 1st command recursive? With find and xarg?

Comment: "recursive" means that all subdirectories are traversed. The `find`/`xarg` command does that. Do you mean something else by "recursive"?

Comment: The 1st command i tested doesnt check for duplicates in folder B. So recursive isnt on for checking in B.

Comment: It's too late at night for me to think clearly about this right now, but please give an example of paths showing where the duplicates are located.

Comment: No one says any importance this needs to be higher priority then your priorities.
File list:
.
├── A
│   └── Excellent
│       ├── 1.png
│       └── 2.png
└── B
    ├── Bad
    │   ├── 1.png
    │   └── 2.png
    └── Excellent
        ├── 1.png
        └── 2.png

Ah i did more tests and wasnt sure why not working. Then i forgot how i had files for test distributed.
So now i found that if duplicate file is in different subfolder then primary file subfolder then it isnt deleted.

So result deleted all in exact same folder content Excellent but not same files in folder Bad.

Comment: fdupes isn't really an alternative as it doesn't keep the files based on specified first path but on modification date as explained  [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/401564/how-does-fdupes-determine-which-file-to-keep-and-which-to-delete-from-set-of-dup)

Comment: In rdfind, when specifying two directories, is the first one kept as original? I don't completely understand the [manpage](https://rdfind.pauldreik.se/rdfind.1.html), it says: _"If A was found while scanning an input argument earlier than than B, A is higher ranked."_

Comment: Another warning about your last suggestion to use `fdupes`: by default, it keeps the oldest file, so if that happens to be on drive B, your are modifying drive A. Worse, it will remove any duplicates that exist on drive A only, which might be excellent files that are duplicated for a reason!